# How to run a command like xargs on a grep output of a pipe of a previous xargs from a command in Bash

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, grep, xargs

I'm trying to understand what's happening here out of curiosity, even though I can just copy and paste the output of the terminal to do what I need to do. The following command does not print anything.

```
ls /opt/local/var/macports/registry/portfiles -1 | sed 's/-.*//g' | sort -u | parallel "sudo port -N install" {} 2>&1 | grep -Po "Use '\K.*(?=')" | parallel "{}"
```

The directory I call ls on contains a bunch of filenames starting with the string I want to extract that ends at the first dash (so stringexample-4.2009 pipes `stringexample` into parallel *(like xargs but to run each line separately)*. After running the command `sudo port install <stringexample>`, I get error outputs like so:

`Unable to activate port <stringexample>. Use 'port -f activate <stringexample>' to force the activation.`

Now, I wish to run `port -f activate <stringexample>`. However, I cannot seem to do anything with the output `port -f activate gettext` that I get to the terminal.

I cannot even do `... | grep -Po "Use '\K.*(?=')" | xargs echo` or `... | grep -Po "Use '\K.*(?=')" >> commands_to_run.txt` (the output stream to file only creates an empty file), despite the shorter part of the command:

`ls /opt/local/var/macports/registry/portfiles -1 | sed 's/-.*//g' | sort -u | parallel "sudo port -N install {}" 2>&1 | grep -Po "Use '\K.*(?=')"`

printing the commands to the terminal. Why does the pipe operator not work here? If the commands I wish to run are outputting to the terminal, surely there's got to be a way to capture them.

Comment: TLDR, it might have something to do with *buffering* due to the long pipeline.

Comment: Oh I see, I did not even know that this happens with pipes.